# How to achieve rounded image on iOS TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, kingfisher

I'm trying to append a rounded image to my custom table cell in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let content : Content = contentsCollection.contents[indexPath.row]
    let channel : Channel = contentsCollection.channel(withId: content.channel!.id)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentCell") as! ContentCell
    cell.layoutSubviews()

    let channelPicture = URL(string: channel.picture)

    cell.channelImageView.kf.setImage(with: channelPicture)

    //Rounded image
    cell.channelImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.channelImageView.frame.height/2    

    return cell
}
```

The problem is, when the view controller is displayed the first time, the image view is still in the square shape. Only the “hidden” cell have the circular image view.

Seems to be the problem documented on this post: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/circular-uiimageview-in-uitableview-cell-e1a7e1b6fe63

But I'm unable to find a workaround for my implementation.

Comment: Try setting the cornerRadius in the `willDisplay:forRowAt:` delegate method.

Comment: try this  cell.channelImageView.clipsToBounds = true

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a `clipsToBounds` missing.

See https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

I create a `RoundImageView` class.

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Implement this one at your storyboard.

[image]

Works for me.

Alternativ: `cell.channelImageView.clipsToBound = true` should work.

Comment: Not working form me `clipsToBound` option, Sorry!
I found the solution, so I will post the answer.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `UIImageView` rounded with

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

An alternative is to add a `CAShapeLayer` to a `UIView`.

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: view.bounds).cgPath
let imageLayer = CAShapeLayer()
imageLayer.mask = mask
imageLayer.frame = view.bounds
imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage
view.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
```

Comment: The thing is to create a `cornerRadius` dynamically depending on the with of the image. Thanks for your answer anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case, only this is working properly:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This line would be before cornerRadius option.

Hope this helps other with same problem.